# How do i get ros_lib and roscpp source files?

Tags: ros, c++, catkin, source, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

i want to implement roscpp to my C++ project to communicate to ROS via TCP. (microcontroller programmed in C++)
Here is a little background:

Some time ago i used rosserial_client on my C++ project. To get rosserial_client source files (.h and .cpp) to my project what i did before was doing this in terminal on ROS indigo :

```
rosrun rosserial_client make_libraries
```

And it got me a nice folder named "ros_lib" containing everything i needed to port rosserial_client to my project. Worked out fine. (.h and .cpp files)

But now i want to use roscpp in my project, to use tcp communication with tcp sockets (i think i need to use transport.h). And i cannot figure out how to get roscpp and roscpp dependencies source files (.h and .cpp) to a single folder with everything working.

I tried to get roscpp from Github then doing a catkin_make on it, but could'nt find something useable after all.

How do i get ros_lib and roscpp source files (in a single folder, with everything working) to port to my C++ project?
Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284575/how-do-i-get-ros_lib-and-roscpp-source-files?/) by [ogensyts](https://answers.ros.org/users/33826/ogensyts/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-03-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here are the complete source build instructions:

- http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Source

**EDIT:** To find the roscpp dependencies in your workspace, first source it, then run:

```
$ rosdep keys roscpp
```

For Kinetic, that shows:

```
rosgraph_msgs
rosconsole
roslang
catkin
xmlrpcpp
std_msgs
message_runtime
rostime
roscpp_serialization
roscpp_traits
message_generation
cpp_common
pkg-config
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2018-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ogensyts](https://answers.ros.org/users/33826/ogensyts/) on 2018-03-06**:
Thank you! Now, do you know which files i need to make tcp connection to my ROS Master? Is there a tutorial on how to use roscpp to connect to master via TCP?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2018-03-06**:
I doubt there is such a tutorial. You should look at the code.

**Comment by [ogensyts](https://answers.ros.org/users/33826/ogensyts/) on 2018-03-06**:
Ok thank you!